# How To Allow External Domains To Map To App Engine App

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am in the process of trying to map custom domains to my app engine app. Basically what we are trying to do is white label our current service and allow external domains such as [www.externaldomain.com](http://www.externaldomain.com) to point to external domain.mydomain.com and serve the same content as mydomain.com. I recently learned that app engine has a 20 domain limit but since I am not actually creating sub domains for external domains and I will always be serving content from a wildcard subdomain will I don’t this this will be a problem.

So just to make this a little clearer, I want to do something like this:

external-domain-1.com (Serves) -> ext-dom-1.mydomain.com

external-domain-2.com (Serves) -> ext-dom-2.mydomain.com

We should be able to figure out the domain thats calling our website and change things such as logo, images etc. Am I correct? If not does anyone have any ideas on how we can still do this within the GCP environment without having to do a major shift, given we already have this set up on App Engine? I was also thinking that we may be able to use a wildcard subdomain to handle the external domains such as

external-domain-1.com (Serves) -> *.mydomain.com

Update:

I did find the article listed in the comments but I’m not sure if it helps https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless. If anyone has any experience doing this please feel free to chime in. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking - how to map external multiple domains to a single GAE App?

Comment: @NoCommandLine. Yes, so I want to map external domains to something like a wildcard subdomain. I would think that it would map something like ext-app.com -> ext-app.myapp.com

Comment: Wildcard Mappings: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/mapping-custom-domains#wildcards

Comment: @JohnHanley I did that and added it to my dispatch.yaml but Im still not able to connect. Im thinking it has something to do with the SSH key not being generated for wildcard domain. But I have not idea how to generate the SSH key

Comment: I am sorry - what problem are you trying to solve? Your question does not mention SSH which is an entirely different protocol and does not use wildcard hostnames. Edit your post to clearly describe your problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry, I got mixed up when trying to figure this problem out. So here is my train of thought. I can redirect external domains to wildcard subdomains. This would look something like this ext-domain.com -> ext-domain.mydomain.com. However, I have the wildcard subdomain problem already figured out so lets forget about that. But when I try to point an external domain to it, it fails. Sorry for the confusion, Ive been at this for a while :(

Comment: @JohnHanley, So I guess I just have to figure out how to point an external domain to my domain, like I originally asked. If I can figure that out, pointing it to wildcard domains should be easy. Also adding external domains to my dispatch.yaml will not work. I would still have to add such domains to the custom domains in app engine and this is limited to 20 domains.

Comment: @JohnHanley, Hey after going through some documentation, I noticed that I may be able to achieve what Im trying to do using a Load Balancer. The tutorial is here https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless. Would this work?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to do something similar to Google's ```appspot.com``` domain i.e. you have a custom domain called ```mydomain.com```. User 1 signs up and picks a name of ```user1``` which automatically gives him ```user1.mydomain.com```. User 1 can also have a custom domain ```user1-customdomain.com``` which in turn will map to ```user1.mydomain.com```.  And you'll have the same scenario for user2, user3, etc. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Yes. I cannot do it through app engine itself because they have a limit on how many domains you can set up. So I have to use something else in order to do it. I was thinking of using a load balancer but I could be wrong. Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using GCPs load balancer and a self signed certificate.

The steps I took to get this to work are as follows:

Follow the instructions from https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless

However when you go to set up the certificate your gonna need to use something such as Lets Encrypt to add both domain names to the certificate. Just as a POC, I created a certificate on my local laptop and uploaded it to the GCP load balancer. So, in order to move forward I am gonna have to create an endpoint that creates the certificate and verifies it when someone wants to point their domain at ours.

If anyone needs any additional help with this please feel free to reach out to me as it was a lot simpler than I thought.

Answer (score -2):

There's 3 main parts to offering custom domains:

1. Pointing domains at your app with DNS.
2. Provisioning and terminating SSL/TLS for each custom domain.
3. Differentiating and handling custom domain http requests in your app once they reach it.

Number one is easy, with one caveat:

- Apex domains (no www or other subdomain) need to be pointed with DNS A records.
- DNS A records must be pointed at an IP address.
- Subdomains can be pointed with a CNAME at another domain/subdomain or with an A record.

Number 2 is probably the most complicated one, because provisioning, renewing, and managing many certs at scale can be tricky. I don't know if App Engine has something built in to handle this (maybe someone knowledgeable there could chime in), but it can also be achieved with a reverse proxy, which will be compatible with almost any stack.

If you want to build a solution with a reverse proxy yourself, I'd recommend Caddy server. Be aware of how acme protocol work, as well as CA rules and rate limits if you go that route. Otherwise you may end up with unexpected issues at some point. If you'd prefer to use a managed service that just does it all for you, I'd recommend approximated.app or CloudFlare's SSL for SAAS (you may need enterprise for some features with CF though).

For number three, depending on how the requests are reverse proxied, you can either use the host header, the x-forwarded-host header, or something equivalent to differentiate custom domain requests from primary domain requests. You can tie that to a tenant/user/entity to load up the right data/content/responses.

How exactly you implement that depends heavily on your app, framework, etc. but it can often be as simple as having something catch primary domain requests in one place, like a router, and all other domains are handled as custom domains in another place.

Comment: Edit your answer to be specific to App Engine which has specific requirements for Custom Domain Mapping. Otherwise, this is not an answer to the question asked.